# Performance penalty of sbt run

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

Is there any performance penalty when running a scala program with **sbt run** instead of using **sbt assembly** and creating an executable jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. In the worst case, sbt will have to compile your project before running it.

Regardless of compilation, sbt runs the program after [forking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29). That incurs overhead as well.

Comment: I'm interested in building and running a Scala application from within a docker container. Do you think it's worth it to use something like `sbt-assembly` to generate a jar and run that in the container? Or should I just use `sbt run`?

Comment: I use `sbt-assembly` because it locks in your dependencies. `sbt run` may need to re-resolve dependencies and that may require access to some nexus repo, or network access in general. Also, sbt-assembly forces you to deal with dependency conflicts early, whereas sbt run doesn't.